# Does a JE must follow directly to an CMP?

Tags: assembly, x86

I wanted to know if a jump instruction as `JE` must directly follow to a `CMP` instruction. Until now, I did always see that first a `CMP` comes and after that a `JMP`. But today I have discover the following:

```
...
CMP DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0xC], EAX
MOV ECX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0x18]
PUSH ESI
MOV ECX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0x18]
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ECX],EAX 
MOV EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0x10]
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EDI], 0x1
JE SHORT crtdll.6C250E66
....
```

First of all, I am beginner. So, I try to understand the assembly language. Logically, I would say that the `JE` instruction is related to the `CMP` instruction at the beginning of that sequence.

So, my self-explanation was that we first compare, then do some `MOV` and `PUSH` operations, after that all we are jumping, is that right?

But, as I mentioned above, normally the jump comes in the next line after the comparison, could one say the reason for that late jump instruction here ? Or is it normal ?

Comment: Since there are plenty of good responses below I'll just add this here. If you look closely at your disassembly you'll realize that the JE could very well be considered to be executed right after the CMP (not logically), the instruction compares EAX with contents located at [EBP+0xC], the instructions that follow never modify [EBP+0xC] and no other instruction will modify the EFLAG registers. Specifically the zero flag. Anyways, just remember that conditional jumps are determined by the modification of the EFLAGS, regardless of the instruction used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is perfectly normal, compilers tend to emit such code for sake of optimization.

Moreover delaying the conditional jump is helpful for instruction prefetching & branch handling. The code is valid too unless the code in between modify the EFLAGS register.

Answer (score 6):

JE checks the zero flag (ZF). So as long as ZF is not modified you can jump any time you want. The same to other jump instructions

Answer (score 4):

JE (Jump on Equal) instructions use a result of a previous operation, this previous operation is usually CMP (compare) but it can be any other of a multitude of similar operations (eg ADD, XOR, etc..) As a matter of fact the operation which will provide the result and the actual jump command may not be consecutive at all, but if intermediate commands do not alter the result flags/registers the program flow will still be valid as intended.

Compilers tend to generate similar code (although there can be automatic optimizations or obfucations) other times custom hand-made code may be written this way for various reasons